# HYPERLINK in if block of a Conga Document

Tags: conga, hyperlink, conga-composer

I am creating a word conga document where I have a field that is to be hyperlink.
The {{HYPERLINK:merge_field:Click Here}} works fine, but I want it to be displayed on a condition, so I put it in IF block. In case where if condition is true, I se Click Here, but it does not work as a hyperlink. Only the text CLick Here is displayed. Is there any alternate to this.

PS: I also created a Formula field to hold the URL and made it Hyperlink in Salesforce and displayed it as {{HTML:Formula_Field}}, it works fine without IF block, but doesn't work in IF block.

Comment: Please add the code what you have tried

Comment: {IF "{{SBQQ__QUOTE_INCLUDE_TENDER_DOCUMENT_LINK}}" = "True" "  {{HYPERLINK:SBQQ__QUOTE_TENDER_DOCUMENT_URL:Click Here}}
" ""}
In case the condition is true I see Click Here on my document but it is not an hyperlink that I can click to redirect

Answer (score 1):

I'm in Conga's support team, and I've been investigating this for one of our customers. Here's what I found out:

When merging a hyperlink field into a Word IF field, I found that not using the "Click here" display text works when merging to a PDF document, but not when merging to a Word document. However when merged to a Word document the link does actually work when you toggle the IF field result's field codes on and click on the "value if true" result.

So I recommend using a Salesforce formula field as you mentioned above as your best option. I confirmed that this works when merging to PDF or Word. But if you want to stick to a Word IF field, you'll need to go without the "Click here" display text, and merge to PDF only.
Regards, Cheryl

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is looking for a workaround, you can use an IF statement in the Salesforce formula to return a blank URL value if your criteria isn't met. This will stop the hyperlink from diplaying on the document.

For example:

IF(Criteria__c = TRUE, "http://www.example.com", "")